# Efficiently finding a matching subnet in a very large pool

Tags: powershell

I have been writing a script that gathers IPAM info given a provided IP address.

It is working, but my current implementation is highly inefficient.

I am using [this script](http://www.gi-architects.co.uk/2016/02/powershell-check-if-ip-or-subnet-matchesfits/) to run `checkSubnet`, which determines if an IP is in a subnet.

First, I query IPAM to gather this `$allSubnets` object:

```
Address         CIDR Description                               VLAN                     
-------         ---- -----------                               ----                     
10.15.10.0        24 DMZ                                       3000                     
10.15.11.0        24 Voice                                     3010                     
10.15.12.0        24 Wireless                                  3020
10.15.13.0        28 Management                                3030
...              ... ...                                        ...
```

Which is then searched like so:

```
$testCon = Test-Connection hostname -Count 1

$allSubnets | ForEach-Object { 
  if((checkSubnet -addr1 ('{0}/{1}' -f $_.Address, $_.CIDR) -addr2 $testCon.IPV4Address.IPAddressToString).Condition -eq $true)
  {
    [pscustomobject]@{
      subnet = ('{0}/{1}' -f $_.Address, $_.CIDR)
      desc = $_.Description
    }
  }
}
```

This works perfectly for smaller queries.
**However, it can take an extremely long time to run** against all the items in `$allSubnets`! Say I want to test 20 IP addresses against a full 2000 subnets, suddenly this query will take a full 2 minutes to complete.

Does anyone have any ideas of how to improve the efficiency of this?

Comment: `IPAM info` it helps not to use acronyms in questions.  I have no idea what you're asking here.  As to your efficiency question: learn about runspaces and run the tests in parallel.

Comment: you could start by filtering subnets which match the first 3 octets i.e. if you're searching for what subnet `10.11.12.13` fits into, you could first search for any ranges that `.StartsWith('10.11.12.')` and then if no results work go back to ranges that `.StartsWith('10.11.')` and so on, at least this way you can filter 99% of cases, and only need to do the heavy lifting in the `checkSubnet` function on a limited number of IPs

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Are you suggesting I spawn 2000 runspaces in the session? Maybe I can break it up, but ideally each query would simply take much less time.

Comment: @colsw This is a good idea, I thought about it but I didn't think about moving backwards like that. It should work.

Comment: @JacobColvin filtering a list is extremely fast, so you'd get a big performance boost out of it in almost every case, you might want to post the code inside your `checkSubnet` function though, as you would most likely be able to speed this up significantly on its own.

Comment: It's a copy paste from the link in the question. @colsw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have access to the full list of subnets, but the tests against the ones posted have shown that this is a bit faster:

first a "simpler" function to see if an IP is in a certain range:

```
Function Find-Subnet ([IPAddress]$SubnetAddress,[byte]$CIDR,[IPAddress]$MatchIP){
    [IPAddress]$Mask = [System.Convert]::ToUInt64(('1'*$CIDR).PadRight(32,'0'),2)
    return (($SubnetAddress.Address -band $Mask.Address) -eq ($MatchIP.Address -band $Mask.Address))
}
```

this takes advantage of bit-shifting, the `[System.IPAddress]` object can be a bit of a performance hit, but it still seems a lot faster than the linked function, and is much more concise, you could always rewrite the `[IPAddress]` casting as another binary function if you really need the extra performance, as we only use the numerical representation of the Address from it in the end.

then I look to limit the number of searches, when searching against 2000+ subnets this should be a massive performance increase, searching against only the few in the question it was only a slight negative though.

```
foreach ($Reg in ('(.*\.).*','(.*\.).*\..*','(.*\.).*\..*\..*')){
    $Prefix = $ToMatch -replace $Reg,'$1'
    Write-Host "Searching subnets beginning with '$($Prefix)'..." -Fore Yellow
    $AllSubnets | ? {$_.Address.StartsWith($Prefix)} | ForEach-Object {
        if (Find-Subnet -SubnetAddress $_.Address -CIDR $_.CIDR -MatchIP $ToMatch){
            $_ ; break
        }
    }
}
```

this loops through the regex snippets `'(.*\.).*'`,`'(.*\.).*\..*'` and `'(.*\.).*\..*\..*'` which when run through the `$Prefix = $ToMatch -replace $Reg,'$1'` will result in something like this:

```
'10.11.12.13' -> '(.*\.).*'         -> '10.11.12.'
'10.11.12.13' -> '(.*\.).*\..*'     -> '10.11.'
'10.11.12.13' -> '(.*\.).*\..*\..*' -> '10.'
```

we then go through the whole list and pull out subnets with addresses starting with the prefix, for any class A subnet this will be slower than just not including it, for B and C it will be roughly the same performance or faster, with B being more likely to be slower, and C being significantly more likely to be much much quicker.

your current function also does not stop searching after it finds the IP. by including the `;break` after returning the matching IP object, we immediately return it and stop searching, if you'd like to store the subnet in a variable you can do `$Result = @(foreach ($Reg in ...) { ... })` to end up with it in `$Result`.

Comment: I really like this - I came up with something very similar right after your comment. `foreach ($i in ('[0-9]*$'),('[0-9]*\.[0-9]*$'),('[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*$')) { $p = $ip -replace $i` That function is also way simpler for what I'm doing. Already I'm seeing lookups under 30ms down from 1800ms :)

Comment: @JacobColvin ah nice, I'll take a look tomorrow at replacing the `[IPAddress]` casts with some more numerical magic to cut it down a bit further if I get a chance, glad to hear it helped out anyway.